# flutter/firebase -error: multiFactorInfo must be provided - how do I get multiFactorInfo from firebase_auth

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I have a working firebase phone sign-in for my app and am trying to reuse the code for 2-factor authentication.

I added multiFactorSession and to differentiate I use the variable globalIs2FactorAuth.

But I get this error: "'phoneNumber != null || multiFactorInfo != null': Either phoneNumber or **multiFactorInfo must be provided**."

I added "multiFactorInfo:" and now am failing to get the required value. **How do I get multiFactorInfo from firebase_auth?**

```
final session = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.multiFactor.getSession();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: globalIs2FactorAuth != true ?phone.toString() :null,
        multiFactorSession: globalIs2FactorAuth == true ?session :null,
        multiFactorInfo: ????,  //<----------------------how do I get this ?
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout)
    .then((value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
To perform 2-factor authentication with Firebase using Flutter and firebase_auth, you need to create a MultiFactorInfo object and pass it to the verifyPhoneNumber method when you have a multiFactorSession.

// Make sure you have initialized Firebase before using FirebaseAuth
// You can call this in your main function or at the start of your app.
void initializeFirebase() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

// Function to fetch the current user data and check if multi-factor is enabled
Future<MultiFactorInfo> getMultiFactorInfo() async {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (user == null) {
    // Handle the case when there's no logged-in user
    throw Exception('No logged-in user');
  }

  // Fetch the user's provider data to find multi-factor information
  final providers = await user.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail();
  if (providers.contains('phone')) {
    // The user has multi-factor enabled using a phone number
    final multiFactorInfo = MultiFactorInfo(phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber);
    return multiFactorInfo;
  } else {
    // Multi-factor is not enabled using a phone number
    throw Exception('Multi-factor authentication is not enabled using a phone number.');
  }
}


you can use the getMultiFactorInfo() function to fetch the MultiFactorInfo and pass it to the verifyPhoneNumber method:

Future<void> startPhoneAuth(bool globalIs2FactorAuth, String phone) async {
  try {
    // Check if multi-factor authentication is required
    if (globalIs2FactorAuth) {
      final multiFactorInfo = await getMultiFactorInfo();
      final session = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.multiFactor.getSession();
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: null, // phoneNumber should be null for 2-factor auth
        multiFactorSession: session,
        multiFactorInfo: multiFactorInfo,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      );
    } else {
      // Regular phone authentication (1-factor)
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone.toString(),
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    // Handle errors here
  }
}

So the startPhoneAuth function will now handle both regular phone authentication and 2-factor authentication. When globalIs2FactorAuth is true, it will use multi-factor authentication with the MultiFactorInfo obtained from the user's data.
```

Comment: fetchSignInMethodsForEmail() and MultiFactorInfo() is unkown. I get the error "The method 'fetchSignInMethodsForEmail' isn't defined for the type 'User'."

Comment: To retrieve the user's provider data and check if multi-factor authentication is enabled, you should use the user.providerData list, and to create a MultiFactorInfo object, you can use PhoneMultiFactorInfo if the user has a phone number associated with their account.